# Get total statistics (sum of a db column) of a model for each month for the last 1 year

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Payments model that stores the payment_date and amount. I want to get the total payment done each month for the last one year.

I started by getting all the payments done in the last 12 months. Now how can I group them for each month and get the total amount for the month. I just need the the following two fields in the result set: "month and year" and "total_amount". I need this data to construct a graph for month wise spending.

I am using rails 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

The following query returns grouped `Payment` objects, so you will need to extract the fields you need, something like this:

```
@payments = Payment.select("SUM(amount) as total_payment, MONTH(payment_date) as month, YEAR(payment_date) as year").group("MONTH(payment_date), YEAR(payment_date)") 
@data = @payments.map {|payment| [payment.amount, payment.month, payment.year]}
```

and then extract the values you need.

Comment: thanks for getting me started, but I am unable to access the resultset (for 2nd query). It returns [#<Payment >, #<Payment >, #<Payment >]. Probably 'select as' is causing the problem with the new attributes not being accessible in the model. The usage above is deprecated in rails 3 and I tried reconstruction the query as: Payment.select("SUM(amount) as total_payment, MONTH(payment_date) as month, YEAR(payment_date) as year").group("MONTH(payment_date), YEAR(payment_date)") ,but still the same problem with resultset.

Comment: A to_sql to the above query returned the following sql query:
SELECT SUM(amount) as total_payment, MONTH(payment_date) as month, YEAR(payment_date) as year FROM `payments` GROUP BY MONTH(payment_date), YEAR(payment_date);   Running it directly gives me the correct result. I believe the ActiveRecord query is correct but somehow I am unable to access the results.

Comment: I think you will have to map the attributes you need to an array (see my update).

Comment: The second statement is failing with the following exception: NoMethodError: undefined method `map' for #<Payment >

I think we are missing something. I tried Payment.sum(:amount) which returned the sum but Payment.select('SUM(amount) as sum') is giving similar resultset ([#<Payment >]) as described above. Payment.select('amount') also returns the required result. It is something with 'select as'. Maybe the ActiveRecord model doesn't generate attribute accessors for them.

Comment: try `@data = @payments.map {|payment| [payment.payment_date, payment.amount]}`

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. But still not able to get the required output due to another problem posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117346/what-is-the-difference-between-modelname-all-and-modelname-where