# What is the difference between ModelName.all and ModelName.where('')

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following relations:
`User --has many--> Reminders --has many--> Payments`

I get all the payments of a user as

```
payments = User.reminders.collect{|reminder| reminder.payments.between(from_date, to_date)}.flatten
```

and then

```
data = payments.select("SUM(amount) as total_payment, MONTH(payment_date) as month, YEAR(payment_date) as year").group("MONTH(payment_date), YEAR(payment_date)").map{|payment| [payment.total_payment, "#{payment.month}/#{payment.year}"]}
```

I was trying to run the above select and group by query on a dataset which failed with the following exception:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
    from (irb):162:in `select'
```

The above query runs fine on Payments.where('') but fails on Payments.all or the dataset which I have obtained above.
On debugging I found that Payments.where('') is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object whereas Payment.all is an Array.

An explanation would help me understand the concept and which way should I take. I don't want to run that group by query for each reminder.payments individually and then sum it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an array of Payment objects at that point, rather than a Relation, which represents a query that hasn't been run yet. There's two ways to approach this problem. The first would be to build payments as a relation rather than an array. I would do this by adding a `has_many :through` relationship between Users and Payments.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reminders
  has_many :payments, :through => :reminders
end

payments = user.payments.between(from_date, to_date)
data = payments.select....
```

The other way to do it would be to just pass the ids from your array to a where clause:

```
payments = user.reminders.collect {...}.flatten
data = Payment.where('id in (?)', payments).select...
```

Comment: Thanks man, you taught me something new today :)  
It works, but user.payments.class returns Array whereas it should be a Relation. I was playing around with it out of curiosity.